"What a wonderful day we've woken up to!" Does this sentence make any sense/natural in English?
I would like to say in the morning that we are going to have a really good day( because we are going on a trip), but I don't know if it is correct in English in this context or if it sounds natural, so I would really appreciate any help, thank you!

Yes, it makes perfect sense, but I would interpret it as a comment on the fine weather rather than a statement that something exciting is planned.

It is grammatical, but it's not the sort of thing you'd normally say in real life. You might call it "purple prose" or "florid writing". It might be suited for a book, or if you want to be a bit silly/dramatic. The normal way might be "what a wonderful day today!"

Something considerably less florid would be "What a wonderful day to wake up to!"

Please use the "edit" button to tell more about why you're concerned that there might be problems. An answer to that will be more helpful than "sure, it's fine."

You might say something like "Today's the day! I'm so excited that we're going to [place]."

Speaking candidely, you might imagine Pangloss making that statement.


"What a wonderful day we've woken up to!"
(because we are going on a trip)

It makes sense. It's makes perfect sense and is not ungrammatical.
Yet, there are probably a whole class of expressions that meet this criterion, yet a native speaker would not phrase it the same way.
What would we say...
"Today's the day! I'm so excited that we're going to [place]."
"I can't wait!"
"In the morning, I woke up, and for a moment thought... wow. We are going to [place]!"
In other circumstances (not with "woken up to") it's possible to say:
"What a fantastic day (we had)!"
"What a wonderful/great day!"

I understand that you have scheduled a trip, therefore you are hoping for a wonderful day ahead.
In English, the line "What a wonderful day we've woken up to!" sounds natural and is grammatically correct. It's a normal way to convey excitement and hope for the day ahead.
As Kate Bunting commented your sentence suggests that you found that the weather was fine (or a sunny day) when you woke up. You can use the following phrases to convey that you are anticipating a good day ahead:

"What a wonderful day ahead!"
"Today is going to be a great day!"
"We're in for a wonderful day!"
"I have a feeling today is going to be amazing!"

These options make it clear that you're looking forward to the journey and the day ahead.

for what it's worth, and this is only my opinion, but I do not agree that it "sounds natural" and is a "normal way to convey excitement". Rather, it sounds like a translation from a foreign language, or someone speaking a dialect of English, in a region of the world where another language is actually the main one.

@Sam It's a natural phrase. You will find that it is regularly used. Similar -  -""We have had the most incredible year and it's felt like every day we have woken up to something incredible that we were expecting. https://www.theguardian.com/music/2010/sep/08/the-xx-mercury-prize-2010

hmm... then... I stand corrected. perhaps it's a regional difference.
